# create a logical column for whether a row contains a string in any column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("cc", "aa", "BB", "dd"), y = c("ee", "dd",
"ff", "gg"), z = c("AA", "gg", "bb", "dd")), row.names = c(NA,
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a binary column indicating whether each row contains "aa" (case insensitive) in any column. So in this case the first two values will be TRUE, and the last true will be FALSE. How can I do this using dplyr? all the answers explain how to filter those rows, rather than how to book-keep them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a vectorized option with [`if_any`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate(xyz = +(if_any(everything(), 
         ~ str_detect(., regex('aa', ignore_case = TRUE)))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  x     y     z       xyz
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 cc    ee    AA        1
2 aa    dd    gg        1
3 BB    ff    bb        0
4 dd    gg    dd        0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(flag = pmap_lgl(., ~"aa" %in% str_to_lower(c(...))))
```

or with `rowwise`:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(flag = "aa" %in% str_to_lower(c_across(everything())))
```

with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, flag := transpose(.SD) %>% map_lgl(~"aa" %in% str_to_lower(.x))]
```

(`transpose` is from `data.table` package)

Answer (score 3):

We can also use this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(xyz = +any(grepl("aa", cur_data(), ignore.case = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  x     y     z       xyz
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 cc    ee    AA        1
2 aa    dd    gg        1
3 BB    ff    bb        0
4 dd    gg    dd        0
```

And also in base R we can do this:

```
Reduce(`+`, apply(df, 1, \(x) +(grepl("aa", x, , ignore.case = TRUE))) |>
         t() |>
         as.data.frame()) -> df$xyz

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  x     y     z       xyz
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 cc    ee    AA        1
2 aa    dd    gg        1
3 BB    ff    bb        0
4 dd    gg    dd        0
```

Comment: To make Anoushiravan's solution case-insensitive, per the question, add "ignore.case": 
mutate(xyz = +any(grepl("aa", cur_data(), ignore.case = TRUE)))

Comment: Oh I just edited my solution to be case sensitive! I did not know that it should be the other way round. Thank you.